# unable to delete file in gcp storage using java which has space in file name

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

```
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, filename);
Blob blob = storage.get(blobId);
boolean isFileDeleted = storage.delete(blobId);
```

Here I am getting `null` for blob which has space for file name. In my bucket the structure is `sample-bucket/Archive 2copy.zip`. Please note the space in the file name.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: In the BlobId.of() call, did you "sample-bucket/Archive 2copy.zip" for the object name,? If so, try instead using:
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("sample-bucket", "Archive 2copy.zip");

Comment: Yes i have tried this

Answer (score 0):

I was using the [Google Java Api - StorageExample.java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/storage) and was able to delete a blob with a space in his name. They are deleting the blob by id.

```
 private static class DeleteAction extends BlobsAction {
    @Override
    public void run(Storage storage, BlobId... blobIds) {
      // use batch operation
      List<Boolean> deleteResults = storage.delete(blobIds);
      int index = 0;
      for (Boolean deleted : deleteResults) {
        if (deleted) {
          // request order is maintained
          System.out.printf("Blob %s was deleted%n", blobIds[index]);
        }
        index++;
      }
    }
  }
```

```
  Expected: <bucket> <path>+
  target/appassembler/bin/StorageExample delete bucket-name 'test file'
  Blob BlobId{bucket=bucket-name, name=test file, generation=null} was deleted
```

Comment: finally found the root cause , the older cloud dependency sdk has this issue.
Now changed to newer version of google cloud java.It resolved the issue

Comment: Hi @adityanirmala, can you please post your solution as answer for this question? This will offer broader visibility for other community users who may see this question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @sllopis sure, am mentioning it here.

Changed from compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.88.0'
to  compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.106.0'

this version changes resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As aditya nirmala pointed out:

> Changed from compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.88.0' to compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.106.0' this version changes resolved the issue.